# jQuery Validator -- only validate onblur event (not onchange)

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validator and would like to validate certain elements when certain events occur.

For example: some textboxes should only validate onblur, whereas some should validate on key change.

I'd like to declare this somehow here.. and how can i do this so the event is specific to the element?

Something like this:

```
$("#form").validate({
       someevent:true,
       rules{
          textbox1:required,
          textbox2:{
              required:true,
              event:onblur // only do onblur
       }
    });
```

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
$("#element").blur(function(){
   $(this).validate({
      // your code here
   })
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work this way. Call to validate() adds validation handler to the element and validation will still work after each key press.

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
  $('form').validate({
    onfocusout: function(e) {
      this.element(e);
    }
    , onkeyup: false
  });
```