# JQuery Form Validation - Onblur

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, onblur

I have a form that uses [jquery form validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/): My question is how to i get the validation to trigger not just on submit but also on blur?  I want it to validate each individual field on blur (not the entire form on blur because i don't want the errors displayed for fields they haven't yet scrolled down to).

I love this plug in if only i could get it to validate each field on blur.  For long forms, i need the user to be be alerted before they fill out the entire form.

I am new to jquery and form validation so if someone knows how to fix this can you be specific on how and what files i need to edit in order to accomplish this.  Thank you.

Comment: You should take a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622232/jquery-validation-onblur and there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592857/jquery-validator-only-validate-onblur-event-not-onchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(function() {
       jQuery("#form").validate({
          onfocusout: function(element) { jQuery(element).valid(); } ,
});
})
     </script>
```

By adding this i got the onblur to work.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) the validation does occur on blur (also on click and on submit). Are you sure that you didn't disable it?
Maybe you set the wrong [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) (scroll down to see the options) or you just didn't set-up validation in the right moment?

Comment: the link you posted above is not validating on blur...? At least on my comp it is not.  I am using firefox.

Comment: @user982853 I mean the first form, to me it validates on blur (try inserting only one character in the first field and pressing tab)

Comment: nope not working.  I redownloaded everything and still not working.  Also doesn't work when i just visit the jquery demo.